# pandas dataframes sub total on columns using pivot table

Tags: pandas, dataframe

looking for sub totals on columns using pivot table in dataframes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"], "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "one", "one", "two", "two"], "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small", "small", "large", "small", "small", "large"], "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

print (df)

pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D'], index=['A'], columns=['C', 'B'], aggfunc={'D': np.sum}, margins=True, fill_value=0, margins_name="Total")


following should be the output:

    D                   
C    large    Total    small    Total
B    one  two          one  two 
A                       
bar    4    7    11      5    6    11
foo    4    0     4      1    6     7
Total  8    7    15      6   12    33
```

Comment: Is last `33` value correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion is better add new `Total` value for second level of `MultiIndex` for possible filtering by first level.

For correct order of columns create ordered [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) with `Total`.

```
df['B'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['B'], 
                              categories= df['B'].unique().tolist() + ['Total'], 
                              ordered=True)
```

For aggregate change `['D']`  to `D` for prevent 3 levels `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                     values='D', 
                     index=['A'], 
                     columns=['C', 'B'], 
                     aggfunc={'D': np.sum}, 
                     fill_value=0)
print (df1)
C   large     small    
B     one two   one two
A                      
bar     4   7     5   6
foo     4   0     1   6
```

Then create new DataFrame with subtotal with `sum` and [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df2 = df1.sum(level=0, axis=1)
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, ['Total']])
print (df2)

    large small
    Total Total
A              
bar    11    11
foo     4     7
```

Then [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) together and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) correct add `Total` to last positions, last add `sum` row:

```
df = df1.join(df2).sort_index(axis=1)
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
print (df)
C     large           small          
B       one two Total   one two Total
A                                    
bar       4   7    11     5   6    11
foo       4   0     4     1   6     7
Total     8   7    15     6  12    18
```